# PHP include/require variables not passed

Tags: php, variables, mysqli, require

EDIT: SOLVED

I'm trying to pass some variables for a mysql connection from a separate file. However, they seem to only be coming through in a string and not as variables.

connect.php:

```
<?php
    function connect(){
        require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db-connect.php');
        $conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn1->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
            }
            echo $conn1->host_info . "\n";
    }
    connect();
?>
```

db-connect.php:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "-";
$password = "--";
$dbname = "---";
?>
```

Message coming through:

```
$servername = "localhost"; $username = "-"; $password = "--"; $dbname = "---";Connection failed: Access denied for user '-'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

notes:
The $password at the end is different that what is in the db-connect.php file. It is an older password that I used to have when I first tried it. Also, the user '-'@'localhost' is an old user and not the user from $username.

Any ideas please and thanks?
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this way around may work better for you.

```
<?php

require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db-connect.php');

   function connect(){

   global $servername, $username, $password, $dbname;

        $conn1 = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn1->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn1->connect_error);
            }
            echo $conn1->host_info . "\n";
    }
    connect();

?>
```

Comment: I did try that way too and no luck. Is it possible that my php5.ini file is screwing it up? I had to create one from scratch and don't know if I have everything I need.

Comment: Hmm, possibly. Have you tried (for debugging puprposes) just placing the variables inside the function as verbatim instead?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine that way. I could keep it that way, I just wanted them in a separate file.

Comment: Are you getting similar issues when you include files residing in the same directory also? It just seems rather odd.

Comment: Yeah, actually. I was having trouble including a file with some js scripts from an included file inside an included file but when i moved the scripts to the first include they worked. They are all in the same directory.

Comment: Hmmm, if it's in the same path, perhaps just require(db-connect.php) would do it then? Otherwise it certainly smells of something more server-ish than code-ish.

Comment: Turns out I was updating a file in a different directory and just had two of the same name files... Ugh. Sorry for the waste of time but appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey, no worries, glad you're back up and working now :P